# edit a string by removing characters without creating a new string, is it legit or not?

Tags: c, algorithm, memory-management

EDIT: I think I've understood how this concept works, this is my code

```
void delete_duplicate(char* str) {
    if (str == NULL) {
        exit(1); 
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++) {
        if (str[i] == str[i + 1]) {
            str[i] = '\0';
        }
    }
}


    int main(void) {
    char str[] = "hhhhhhhheeeeeeeeyyyyyyyyyyy"; 
    delete_duplicate(str); 
    return 0; 
}
```

---

the output string is "00...0h0...000e0...000y" (with lots of zeros). if the string is "abbbb", the string becomes "a" and not "ab".

---

I was thinking about an algorithm for this exercise:

> given a string, for example "ssttringg" the output must be "string". the function has to remove one character if and only if the current character and the next character are the same.

the exercise expects a function declared like this:

```
extern void delete_consecutive(char* str);
```

this is my algorithm:

- loop: if the current character is equal to the next character, increment length by 1, and repeat until zero terminator is reached.

critical part: dynamic memory allocation.

- allocate enough memory to store the output. Why did I say this is the critical part? because I have to do it in a void function, therefore I can't create a second string, allocate enough memory with malloc, and then return it at the end. I need to edit the original string instead. I think I can do it by means of a realloc, and by decrementing the size of the string. But I don't know how to do it, and more important: I don't know if it's legit to do it, without losing data. I think I'm overcomplicating the homework, but it's a void function, therefore I can't simply create a new string and copying characters in it, because I can't return it.

if it's not clear, I'll edit the question.

Comment: I'm lost. You seem to be asking us if *you* can do something, then proceed to try to explain how you *would* code it, but haven't ?? I sense the short version of this "How do I remove consecutive duplicate characters in a string?" , then proceed to show us how you've tried to do just that, and ask specific questions if you weren't able to do so.

Comment: Yes it is legitimate to edit a string in place. You cannot and need not realloc the original string. Just remove the characters and place the null terminator at the new position.

Comment: because I don't know how to do it, I've written this question to discuss this exercise and trying to figure it out. I'm completely lost

Comment: Why would it *not* be legit? It's not a `const char *` therefore you are allowed to edit the string in place. Why would you need to `realloc`? Don't do that, someone else is passing a buffer, it's the caller's job to keep track of the memory.

Comment: You don't need to do any dynamic memory allocation.  You can modify the string in-place.  (Just make sure you pass in only writable strings.)

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. the null terminator doesn't delete the current character. If I do this, the string has a lot of zeros but 0 count as character

Comment: What should happen if there are more than 2 characters in a row? Should aaaabbbb become ab?

Comment: modify the string in place as per the first answer

Comment: @klutt 's question is important (and, in fact, makes a reader/writer enumeration scan *easier*, or *harder*, depending on the answer): What is the expected result of `"11112222233333"` ? Is it `"123"` ? if not, then what is it ?

Comment: Do you really need to modify any strings? The assignment asks of you to *output* the new string. Just print the characters of the original string, skipping duplicates.

Comment: You cannot do `realloc` for two reasons: 1. You don't know if the buffer was allocated on the heap. 2. `realloc` may move the buffer, and you don't have any ways of communicating its new position to the caller.

Comment: The string ends at the null terminator. The buffer may be larger and contain more characters, but characters after the null terminator are not part of the string, by definition. They are of no concern to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern is called a *retention scan* (also a *reduction scan*, depending on your perspective), and is *very* common in algorithms that dictate discarding characters whilst keeping others, based on some condition. Often, the condition can change, and sometimes even the methods for starting the scan are somewhat altered

In it's simplest form, it looks something like this, as an example: An algorithm used to discard all but numeric (digit) characters:

1. Start with reader `r` and writer `w` pointers at the head of the string.
2. Iterate over the string from beginning to terminator using `r`. The `r` pointer will *always* be incremented exactly once per iteration.
3. For each iteration, check to see if the current character at `r` satisfies the condition for retention (in this case, is the character a digit char?). If it does, write it at `w` and advance `w` one slot.
4. When finished. `w` will point to the location where your terminator should reside.

```
#include <ctype.h>

void delete_nondigits(char *s)
{
    if (s && *s)
    {
        char *w = s;
        for (char *r = s; *r; ++r)
        {
            if (isdigit((unsigned char)*r))
                *w++ = *r;
        }
        *w = 0;
    }
}
```

Pretty simple.

Now, the algorithm for in-place consecutive-run compaction is more complicated, but has a highly similar model. Because retention is based on a prior-value already-retained you need to remember that last-kept value. You *could* just use `*w`, but the algorithm is actually easier to understand (and advance `w`) if you keep it in a separate memo `char` as you're about to see:

1. Start with reader `r` and writer `w` pointers as we had before, but starting at *second* slot of the string, and a single memo `char` variable `c` initialized to the first character of the string.
2. Iterate over the string using `r` until termination encounter. The `r` pointer will *always* be incremented exactly once per iteration.
3. For each iteration, check to see if the current character at `*r` is the same as the memo character `c` If it is, do nothing and continue to the next iteration.
4. Otherwise, if the character at `*r` is *different* than the memo character `c`, save it as the new value for `c`, write it to `*w`, and advance `w` one slot.
5. When finished, terminate the string by setting a terminator at `*w`.

The only hitch to this algorithm is supporting a zero-length string on inception, which is easily circumvented by checking that single condition first. I leave actually implementing it as an exercise for you. (hint: only do the above if `(s && *s)` is true).

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the string passed as a parameter if it is modifiable.

Example:

```
void deleteFirstChar(char *str)
{
    if(str && *str)
    {
        
        memmove(str, str + 1, strlen(str));
    }
}

//illegal call
//string literals cannot be changed
void foo(void)
{
    char *str = "Hello";
    deleteFirstChar(str);
}

//legal call
void bar(void)
{
    char str[] = "Hello";
    deleteFirstChar(str);
}
```

Comment: i think the reason for the downvote is that this doesnt do what the question posed, although i get why you posted this answer

Comment: @pm100 I am not going to do his homework

Comment: @pm100, the question was if it was legit to delete chararcters in a string, not how to remove duplicates.

Comment: @HAL9000 - i didnt downvote, but somebody did, I think this is a fine answer

Comment: @pm100, sorry, didn't mean to criticize, only expand on your comment.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer, but consider this code:

```
    char str[] = "strunqg";
    printf("before: %s\n", str);
    modifystring(str);
    printf("after:  %s\n", str);
```

where the "`modifystring`" function looks like this:

```
void modifystring(char *p)
{
    p[3] = 'i';
    p[5] = p[6];
    p[6] = '\0';
}
```

This is totally "legit".  It would not work, however, to call

```
    char *str = "strunqg";
    modifystring(str);            /* WRONG */
```

or

```
    modifystring("strunqg");      /* WRONG */
```

Either of these second two would attempt to modify a string literal, and that's not copacetic.

Answer (score 0):

```
void delete_duplicate(char* str)
{
    if(str && *str)
    {
        char *writeTo = str, *readFrom = str;
        char prev = 0;
        while(*readFrom)
        {
            if(prev != *readFrom)
            {
                prev = *readFrom++;
                *writeTo++ = prev;
            }
            else
            {
                readFrom++;
            }
        }
        *writeTo = 0;
    }
}


int main(void) 
{
    char str[] = "hhhhhhhheeeeeeeeyyyyyyyyyyy"; 
    delete_duplicate(str); 
    printf("`%s`\n", str);
    return 0; 
}
```